# Subtract two clock times in PHP

Tags: php

It wont work every time my time out is over 12 AM.

for example, Time in is 5 PM and Time out is 1 AM.
The output should be 8 hours but instead it display 16 hours

```
$x = ':'; 

$hour1 = '5';
$minute1 = '00';
$meridiem1 = 'PM';

$hour2 = '1';
$minute2 = '00';
$meridiem2 = 'AM';

$timein = $hour1.$x.$minute1.$meridiem1;
$timeout = $hour2.$x.$minute2.$meridiem2;

$a = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'g:i A', $timein );
$b = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'g:i A', $timeout );

$interval = $a->diff($b);

$interval_hour = $interval->h;
$interval_minute = $interval->m;

echo 'Employee'.'<br>';
echo 'Time in: '.$timein.' '.'<br>';
echo 'Time out: '.$timeout.' '.'<br>';

echo 'Total: '.$interval_hour.' h'.' & '.$interval_minute.' m'.'<br>';
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck? How should the code distinguish between the two cases if you don't provide the date, but only the time?

Comment: Is it possible without using date?

Comment: The first DateTime object you created is `2021-11-10 17:00:00.000000`, the second one is `2021-11-10 01:00:00.000000`. From 17 down to 1, or from 1 up to 17 - that is sixteen hours difference, no matter which way you look at it. Not sure how you'd want to arrive at eight here.

Comment: Are you sure you did not simply get `am` and `pm` confused here ...? `5am` to `1pm`, which would be `05:00` to `13:00`- now _that's_ a difference of eight hours.

Comment: Thank you. I get it now :)